# How to retrieve all comments of the Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I need to get all comments of the Fan Page. Not only from the wall, but from the albums, photos, notes, etc.

I solved this problem in such a way. First I get all objects (albums, notes, etc.) of the Fan Page. Second I get commets to each object, using FQL multi query.

```
    // Import comment list
    $facebook = \Yii::app()->facebook->setUserAccessToken();
    $commentsColumns = array(
        'xid', 'object_id', 'post_id', 'fromid', 'time', 'text', 'username', 
        'reply_xid', 'post_fbid', 'app_id', 'likes', 'comments', 'user_likes', 
        'is_private', 'id',
    );
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 30;
    while (($offset <= count($objectIdList)) && ($offset <= count($postIdList))) {
        $currentObjectIdList = array_slice($objectIdList, $offset, $limit);
        $currentPostIdList = array_slice($postIdList, $offset, $limit);
        $multiQuery = array(
            'comments' =>
                ' SELECT '.implode(', ', $commentsColumns).' '.
                ' FROM comment '.
                ' WHERE ((object_id IN ('.implode(',', $currentObjectIdList).')) '.
                ' OR (post_id IN ('.implode(',', $currentPostIdList).'))) '.
                ' AND (time >= ' . $lastCommentTime . ') ' .
                ' ORDER BY time DESC '.
                ' LIMIT 1000 ',
            'users' => 
                ' SELECT uid, name ' .
                ' FROM user ' .
                ' WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments) ',
            'pages' => 
                ' SELECT page_id, name ' .
                ' FROM page ' .
                ' WHERE page_id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments) '
        );
        $multiQueryResult = $facebook->api(array(
            'method'   => 'fql.multiquery',
            'queries'  => $multiQuery
        ));

        // Parse multi query results
        $from = array();
        foreach ($multiQueryResult as $result) {
            switch ($result['name']) {
                case 'comments':
                    $commentList = $result['fql_result_set'];
                    break;
                case 'users':
                case 'pages':
                    foreach ($result['fql_result_set'] as $set) {
                        switch ($result['name']) {
                            case 'users':
                                $from[$set['uid']] = $set['name'];
                                break;
                            case 'pages':
                                $from[$set['page_id']] = $set['name'];
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Save comments to local DB
        foreach ($commentList as $commentData) {
            $comment = new Comment();
            $comment->fbId          = $commentData['id'];
            $comment->fbPageId      = $this->fbId;
            $comment->from          = array(
                'id'    => $commentData['fromid'],
                'name'  => isset($from[$commentData['fromid']]) ? $from[$commentData['fromid']] : null,
            );
            $comment->message       = $commentData['text'];
            $comment->created_time  = $commentData['time'];
            $comment->likes         = $commentData['likes'];
            $comment->save();
        }

        // Next step
        $offset = $offset + $limit;
    }
```

This solution works, but is not pretty fast. Has anyone know better solution?

Comment: What actually slows it down, FQL multi-query or objects ids retrieval? Do you get object ids using [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)?

Comment: Retrieval of objects IDs is pretty fast (thanks to batch requests). But FQL query is too slow. Maybe because it is performed for more than 100 object and more than 200 posts.

Comment: You probably right, Facebook need to get the data from too many sources which is slow. I've seen a lot of simple SQL queries that slow as hell. Maybe you can speed it up by splitting this task is several queries which may run in parallel...

Comment: Splitting this task is a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the graph API method given below,
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/feed to get all the feeds of the user .It will return an json array,from there you can collect the comments,statuses etc etc

Comment: Please, read my question more carefully. I've asked about **comments** (not posts) of the **page** (not current user).

Comment: Noow facebook require an access token to do the request. 
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}